# How can i reach the treasure in the right door of Desert Temple?

Tags: candy-box-2

How can i reach the treasure in the right door of Desert Temple? I can't jump there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the teleport spell and the enchanted spear to make a staircase with the summoned tribals